# C# SendKeys sending other keys aswell

Tags: sendkeys

When I use SendKeys inside my software to send a key to a game. It also send other buttons like Enter, Tab, V. I just want to Send "Q" and "E" keys but it keep sending other ones.

Comment: Without code, nobody can help you.

Comment: @Nikolaus gonna upload it soon